# Multiple Folders in Explorer

Tags: codelite

The Explorer in Codelite is very helpful. But it seems not to be possible to have more than one directory included in it.
Is there a plugin or a way I couldn't find until now, to have more than one folder in the Explorer in Codelite?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about CodeLite 9.X, 
The `Explorer` view can handle multiple folders

You can add a folder from the main menu:
`File -> Open -> Open Folder`

Or:

Drag and Drop a folder from the Finder/Windows Explorer/File Manager on the explorer tab

Eran